# Serializing a map with type_info as key with boost.

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I am writing a game with an entity-component-system. My entity manager stores components in a 2D map that looks like this:

```
map<const type_info*, vector<shared_ptr<Component>> > components;
```

Each component has its own serialize function, with the exception of the abstract base, as it has no varibles to save. I am using boost to try and save / load the manager. And i get two errors:

```
error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'type_info'   f:\boost\boost\serialization\access.hpp 116
error C2512: 'type_info' : no appropriate default constructor available f:\boost\boost\serialization\access.hpp 130
```

Naturally when i get errors like these i just include the necesseray serialization headers, and while boost has four headers with type_info in them, none of them work. (<- and that is my boost expertiese, trying to import any header with type_info in it)

The entity manager's serialize function looks like this:

```
template<class A> void serialize(A& arc, const unsigned int version){
    arc & /* other vars */ & components;
};
```

Disclaimer: I only started using boost a day ago, so I dont know if/how i am shooting myself in the foot.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/extended_type_info.html

Comment: The problem is not `type_info` but `type_info*`, const no less, I think.